# Transfer last word of the line to a new line in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

So I have around 40k lines of `INSERT` like this:

`INSERT INTO dbo.table (something) values ('something') GO`

But I want to move the word `GO` on a new line, using Regex:

```
   INSERT INTO dbo.table (something) values ('something') 
    
    GO
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Replace `\w+$` with `\n$&`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just extract `GO` and replace it with `\nGO`.

Try this one:

```js
const input = `
INSERT INTO dbo.table (something) values ('something') GO
INSERT INTO dbo.table (something) values ('something') GO
INSERT INTO dbo.table (something) values ('something') GO
`

const res = input.replace(/(\w+)$/gm, '\n$1')
console.log(res)
```

Comment: I'm assuming `GO` is just an example here. Also, this will replace all instances of `GO`, not just the one at the end. Even worse, it will replace "GO" when it's part of another word.

Comment: You are right, so checking for last word in this case will be much better, thanks.